# while loping through a list do we get a copy or an object itself?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, copy

code

```
lst = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

for i in lst:
    i.append(0)
```

makes lst look like this
`[[1, 2, 3, 0], [4, 5, 6, 0], [7, 8, 9, 0]]`

The result is unexpected for me, since usually when we loop through a list, in **i** we seem to get a *copy *of the next value. I mean, code

```
for i in lst:
    i = 3
```

doesn't change anything in the lst, so in every iteration **i** is just a temporary copy, right?

Comment: lists are mutable, integers are not. Also `i.append(0)` applies to the object, `i = 3` just redefines the name

Comment: Of course your last code doesn't change anything in `lst` because you're not modifying it at all.

Comment: During the 1st passage in the loop, `i` points to the sublist `[1, 2, 3]` ; `i.append(0)` modifies this sublist in place, hence the result; on the other hand, `i = 3` makes i 'forget' the sublist and point to the integer 3 instead.

Comment: Lists are mutable. list.append is a method that mutates the object (changes the inner state of the object). The variable still points to the same place in memory because you don't do anything with variable `i`, you do stuff with inner state of the object. But any time you do i= anywhere, the memory that the variable points to changes (unless of course you do an assignment with itself that does nothing). It's not like in C or other languages that variable itself is a place of memory - in Python each variable is basically a pointer to something else

Comment: This might be something you want to read: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)